# how i get the right UITableViewCell objects textLable.text value，these reusable cells stored in a MutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm learning The development of iOS ,and I have  a  question .I  can't debug it ,Google can’t give me answer.

Maybe I did not find a right way.

This  question is when I create `UITableViewCell` objects and I reuse them ,and  these cells are stored in  a MutableArray, when I reuse cells  from Buffer pool ,and get the value from the MutableArray, but the value  of `textLable.text`  is not right .

my code :

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString * timeRing = @"ring";
    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:timeRing];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:timeRing];
    }else{
        while ([cell.contentView.subviews lastObject]!=nil) {
            [[cell.contentView.subviews lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    if (self.cellArray.count<self.ringArray.count) {

        self.timeRingItem = self.ringArray[indexPath.row];
        cell.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        cell.textLabel.text= self.timeRingItem.ringName;
        [self.cellArray addObject:cell];
    }
    else{

        cell = self.cellArray[indexPath.row];

    }

    return  cell;
}
```

when the code run to `cell = self.cellArray[indexPath.row];` ,the `cell.textLable.text` is wrong

so why? thanks for giving me answer.

Answer (score 0):

The nature of a tableview means that cells will be re-used. When the user scrolls, it's going to take the top cell that just disappeared, and use it for the new cell. If you want to reference data, you need to keep the data in a separate array that's independent from the cells.